# How should the daily updatedb cronjob be configured?

Tags: cron, vmware, updatedb

For the longest time I have a huge performance issue in my Ubuntu VM, as every day at some time the cpu would be at a 100%, pointing to the fuse process that mounts the shared directories under `/mnt/hgfs` as the problem. To find out what was causing it I did

```
$ sudo lsof /mnt/hgfs/
[sudo] passord for myuser: 
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
find    20811 nobody    4r   DIR   0,45   327680 1644542 /mnt/hgfs/SharedData/Users/myuser/Pictures/Lightroom/Main Previews.lrdata/9
```

Followed by finding the parent of that `find` process:

```
$ sudo pstree -s -p 20811
systemd(1)───anacron(20328)───sh(20470)───run-parts(20472)───locate(20715)───updatedb.findut(20720)───updatedb.findut(20728)───su(20786)───sh(20809)───find(20811+
```

So it was a cron job that caused this by invoking `updatedb`. That's fine, I know `updatedb` has a config file at `/etc/updatedb.conf` and so I added `/mnt/hgfs` to the `PRUNEPATHS` variable and thought that would be it.

Turns out it was not. The same problem kept coming up.

OK, so grepping the `/etc/cron.*` directories I quickly discovered `/etc/cron.daily/locate`, and this time I took a look and discovered the script sets its own custom configuration, including `PRUNEPATHS`. It does not seem to consult `/etc/updatedb.conf` at all. This seems highly confusing to me. What is the point of a config file that is not used in the daily updates? Now I need to hack a system supplied file for this to work. That seems counter-intuitive and not something I am used to from Ubuntu.

Could someone explain the logic here, alternatively how this was *supposed* to work?